# Oven warmer trips GFCI and bake element doesn't work

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, gfci, gas, oven

I have a Kenmore gas oven model 790.75663201. Started the warmer for the first time since I bought the house five years ago. The GFCI next to it tripped after a couple of minutes. Happens every time. Since then, the bake element doesn't ignite. The broiler and stove top work fine though. What could the issue be?[image]

Comment: Does the breaker in question have a TEST button on it?

Comment: Yes. It works fine.

Comment: Can you provide us with photos of the breaker in question then?

Comment: Added a picture of the outlet with the breaker that trips. Power to the oven goes through it.

Comment: You say a breaker trips, but then, your picture is centered on a GFCI receptacle. Could you maybe remove all slang and contractions, and review your use of words like "breaker" (which means circuit breaker), "GFCI", "receptacle", "trip", etc. to assure they conform with conventional meanings? You can [edit] as needed.

Answer (score 3):

### Igniter grounded out and failed

Since your stove appears to use an electronic hot-surface igniter for the oven burner, *and* it's most likely a GFCI that tripped instead of a regular breaker, then I suspect the igniter grounded out and failed when you turned the warming function on, which led to the GFCI trip.  You'll need to replace it (or have an appliance tech replace it for you) to revive the oven, most likely.

Comment: Interesting. It trips only when I turn in the warmer though. When I turn on baking, it doesn't trip but the bake element doesn't ignite and no gas seems to be coming out. The igniter doesn't glow either.

Comment: I gotta agree with 3ph, the baking element has a ground fault and your igniter has failed. I've had to replace igniters in my gas stove (for the oven) a couple of times, it's not hard.

Comment: @RaulSantelices -- does the warmer use its own burner, or the main oven burner?

Comment: I don't know for sure. It might be its own because it seems to warm up a little before the GFCI trips, whereas the bake element does not heat up at all (the igniter doesn't seem to glow).